# WPF DataGrid Does not show data when the ItemsSource is set

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to update a DataGrid from my sdf file using C# in Visual Studio 2010. The DataGrid is as follows.

```
<Grid Height="auto" Name="grid1" Width="auto" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=grid1, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="200" Name="DGWidth"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="600" Name="PIWidth"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
              Height="{Binding ElementName=grid1, Path=ActualHeight}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Name="PIView" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="{Binding ElementName=PIWidth, Path=ActualWidth}"
              IsReadOnly="True"/>
</Grid>
```

I am trying to populate the PIView DataGrid. To do that I am passing the DataGrid Reference to a method `updatePIView` in a manager class.

```
 public class PTManager
{

    public PTManager()
    {
    }

    public void updatePIView(ref DataGrid pIView, DateTime datetime)
    {
        PTDate date = PTDatabase.GetDt(datetime);
        SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = PTDatabase.GetAdaperForPIViewForDt(date);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        pIView.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

In side the method I am setting the ItemsSource. It worked for another DataGrid (with a single column table) which was loaded just after loading the main window.

I am trying load data in `PIView` on a selection event. I can see the data in the table. But when the default view of the table is set as the `ItemsSource` nothing happens. WPF does not produce any error or warning.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use WPF as if it were Windows Forms... it's *not* Windows Forms.

In WPF, we use the `DataGrid` by loading data in a suitable form into a property and data bind that property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionProperty}" ... />
```

...

```
// preferably implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on this property
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> YourCollectionProperty { get; set; }
```

...

```
YourCollectionProperty = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>(GetData());
```

If you are unfamiliar with data binding in WPF, please refer to the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN... you also need to correctly set the DataContext` of your view to an instance of the class that has the property to data bind to for example:

```
DataContext = new SomeViewModelWithTheBindableProperty();
```

Comment: I do not need a collection. Therefore, I tried it without the collection. But I don't know why It didn't work. BTW, I assigned `PTManager` as the viewmodel class and set it as static resource for the window to bind a property `DataView  PIView` without the twoway mode.

Comment: Your `PTManager` class is *not* a view model because view models know nothing about the views. Any 'view model' that has UI related properties (eg. of type `DataGrid`) are *not* view models.

Comment: I have removed those `DataGrid`'s from PTManager. Communicating using the the property which does not have any knowledge about the interface.